# Is there any image slider (react native) similar with react-native-image-slider-show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to use image sider that can move by pressing right and left corner.
I found this react-native-image-slider-show .but it cannot use correctly .console warning show about component mounting.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider-show

[image]

I also checked image slider box . but they are not ok for my project.
my project has already swiper for image.
I want to do is to move image on swiper card.
if use slider box, it conflict with swiper action.
if there is just right and left corner press image slider.

I already have swipe in my component, I try to use image slider because I want to slide multiple images of users on swiper card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Package

```
npm install react-native-swiper
```

It will resolve your issue. Using this package when you click left or right of that image it willl move to next image.

https://gist.github.com/akulsr0/33ca485734b10d844ee7666f2955d132

Here is a link where you can check more about this Package.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that code snippet. Also checkout, RNUI App - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akul.reactnativeui&hl=en for more such references.